# Test multiple Chrome browser sessions with Selenium + Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am in a situation where I need to test a website in Chrome where I have two different users logged in at once and then I want to switch between each instance and test different functions

Is there a way to open a second chrome instance which will be free of any cookies etc (so the user logged into first instance won't be still logged in) and then I can login as second user on the second instance and keep both instances with both users logged in?

Or would I have to resort to opening up a second browser ie Firefox and do it that way? Our suite is only currently configured to run with Chrome and ChromeDriver so I would have to update it so it could also open a firefox instance with geckordriver and test that.

Comment: Using a separate Webdriver is the answer. Cookies (thereby sessions) are maintained/stored by the browser and bound to a URL. So if both windows point to the same URL they both have the same session.

Comment: yep... use 1 thread per driver per browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* is opened with [a specific set of command line switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371586/why-does-selenium-chromedriver-use-less-resources-than-regular-chrome/65363915#65363915) being  scoped out from a newly **scoped_dir**. As an e.g. on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9640_113432031
```

So to keep the two user sessions seperate you can initiate two different Chrome based user sessions as follows:

```
// initiates the first Chrome session
WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();

// initiates the second Chrome session
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
```

When you intent to switch between these instances you have to bring back Selenium's focus on the required session using the following line of code:

```
// to focus on the first Chrome session
((JavascriptExecutor) driver1).executeScript("window.focus();");

// to focus on the second Chrome session
((JavascriptExecutor) driver2).executeScript("window.focus();");
```